# Lenovo T60p ALT keys not working

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-layout, thinkpad

I have a Lenovo T60p laptop, where the Alt and AltGr keys have stopped working.
I use a Danish keyboard layout, where these keys are essential to produce many characters.

I have done the following:

- Re-installed Windows 7
- Installed a new (used) keyboard.

Alt is still not working (But CTRL+ALT+DELETE does work).

I think it is unlikely that both the keyboards I tried have the same defect. Do I need a driver for the Thinkpad ? Some other software issue that could cause this ?

Comment: If CTRL-ALT-DEL works, then the ALT key works.  What makes you think it's not working? If you turn on Windows' On-screen keyboard, does it reflect that your pushing the Alt key when you do?  If you boot from a different OS (say a Linux LiveCD) does Alt work as expected?

Comment: The characters that need an Alt combination to type is not working. Alt+2 should get me @, etc. I have, of course, checked that the correct keyboard layout is selected.

Comment: ok I'm not sure how the Danish keyboards are laid out, but on a standard English keyboard to get the @ (over the 2) you use Shift-2 not Alt-2.

Comment: By  [Windows Keyboard Layouts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/globalization/keyboards/kbdda.html), the _Commercial At_ (`@`) character should be  produced using **AltGr+2**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even it is very old question - I will answer.

Because It bothers me a lot of time with my Lenovo 700 17-ISK.

The 2 Alt keys - didn't work on my NEW Lenovo computer.

The solution is in **Intel Graphics Settings** software.

How to solve :

1. Open Intel Graphics Settings in your computer.
2. Go to **Options And Support**
3. Go to **Hot Key Manager**
4. **Disable** the option "Manage Hot Keys".
5. Click on **Apply** and close the software.

Now the Alt keys - return to work very good.